Unlink a particular element from linked component
I'm trying to add a button inside the component which is link ()as a whole already. But I want my button to be unlinked but also positioned inside that linked component.
I mean when I click on that button it should do what function I assigned using (onClick)but not redirecting to the component Link.
I'm working with SPA using React.
return(


{name}
{cuisine}
Rating: {rating}
Delivery Time: (deliverytime+"minutes"}
{costfortwo}
Add/button

Placing a button element within an anchor tag, and more generally placing interactive elements within other interactive elements, is incorrect semantic HTML. Please try to reconsider your UI/UX. Besides that, we can't address issues in code we can't see, so please do [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with that has the problem.

you can use stopPropogation function to achieve that purpose.
<Link href="/link-location">
   <button onClick={(e)=>{
      e.stopPropogation()
      //button onClick functionality goes here
   }}>button text</button>
</link>

